# Showing user profile data on front-end

Tags: functions, users, front-end, profiles

I'm making a profile-page so my members can update they're details trough the front-end. The problem is that the select-box named "Province" won't show the correct data when the page loads.

How can i make the select-box load the correct data when the user enters the page?

Here is the code i have in **functions.php** at the moment. This code works when i update the Province trough the wordpress admin.

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields' );

function extra_user_profile_fields( $user ) { ?>
    <h3><?php _e("Extra profile information", "blank"); ?></h3>

    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="facebook"><?php _e("Facebook URL"); ?></label></th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="facebook" id="facebook" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'facebook', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
                <span class="description"><?php _e("Please enter your Facebook URL."); ?></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><label for="twitter"><?php _e("Twitter"); ?></label></th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="twitter" id="twitter" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'twitter', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
                <span class="description"><?php _e("Please enter your Twitter Username."); ?></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><label for="dob"><?php _e("Date Of Birth"); ?></label></th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="dob" id="dob" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'dob', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
                <span class="description"><?php _e("Please enter your Date Of Birth, ex: 13/06/1983"); ?></span>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th><label for="city"><?php _e("City"); ?></label></th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="city" id="city" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'city', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
                <span class="description"><?php _e("Please enter your city."); ?></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><label for="province"><?php _e("Province"); ?></label></th>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control" name="province" id="province">
                    <option value="Sør-Trøndelag" <?php selected( 'Sør-Trøndelag', get_the_author_meta( 'province', $user->ID ) ); ?>>Sør-Trøndelag</option>
                    <option value="Nord-Trøndelag" <?php selected( 'Nord-Trøndelag', get_the_author_meta( 'province', $user->ID ) ); ?>>Nord-Trøndelag</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<?php }

add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields' );

function save_extra_user_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) ) { return false; }

    update_usermeta( $user_id, 'facebook', $_POST['facebook'] );
    update_usermeta( $user_id, 'twitter', $_POST['twitter'] );
    update_usermeta( $user_id, 'dob', $_POST['dob'] );
    update_usermeta( $user_id, 'phone', $_POST['phone'] );
    update_usermeta( $user_id, 'address', $_POST['address'] );
    update_usermeta( $user_id, 'address', $_POST['address'] );
    update_usermeta( $user_id, 'city', $_POST['city'] );
    update_usermeta( $user_id, 'province', $_POST['province'] );
    update_usermeta( $user_id, 'postalcode', $_POST['postalcode'] );
    update_usermeta( $user_id, 'gender', $_POST['gender'] );
}
?>
```

This is the code I have in **page-profile.php**. All fields looks to work fine, but the select-box wont show the correct data when page is loaded.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Update Profile
*/

$wpdb->hide_errors(); nocache_headers(); global $userdata; get_currentuserinfo();

if(!empty($_POST['action'])){

    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/user.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/registration.php');

    check_admin_referer('update-profile_' . $user_ID);

    $errors = edit_user($user_ID);

    if ( is_wp_error( $errors ) ) {
        foreach( $errors->get_error_messages() as $message )
            $errmsg = "$message";
    }

    if($errmsg == '')
    {
        do_action('personal_options_update',$user_ID);
        $d_url = $_POST['dashboard_url'];
        wp_redirect( get_option("siteurl").'?page_id='.$post->ID.'&updated=true' );
    }
    else{
        $errmsg = '<div class="box-red">' . $errmsg . '</div>';
        $errcolor = 'style="background-color:#FFEBE8;border:1px solid #CC0000;"';

    }
}
get_header(); get_currentuserinfo(); ?>
    <div class="container" style="margin-top: 30px;">
    <div id="content" role="main" class="col-md-9">

        <form name="profile" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <?php wp_nonce_field('update-profile_' . $user_ID) ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="from" value="profile" />
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update" />
            <input type="hidden" name="checkuser_id" value="<?php echo $user_ID ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="dashboard_url" value="<?php echo get_option("dashboard_url"); ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id" value="<?php echo $user_id; ?>" />

                <?php if ( isset($_GET['updated']) ): $d_url = $_GET['d'];?>
                        <div class="alert alert-success">Din profil ble oppdatert</div>
                <?php elseif($errmsg!=""): ?>
                        <div class="alert alert-danger"><?php echo $errmsg;?></div>
                <?php endif;?>
            <style>
                .row {margin-bottom: 10px;}
            </style>
                    <h2>Update profile</h2>
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label>Fornavn</label>
                        <input type="text" class=" form-control" name="first_name" id="first_name" value="<?php echo $userdata->first_name ?>" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label>Etternavn</label>
                        <input type="text" name="last_name" class="mid2 form-control" id="last_name" value="<?php echo $userdata->last_name ?>" />
                        </div>
                     <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label>Epost <span style="color: #F00">*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" name="email" class="mid2 form-control" id="email" value="<?php echo $userdata->user_email ?>" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label>Nytt passord </label>
                        <input type="password" name="pass1" class="mid2 form-control" id="pass1" value="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label>Gjenta nytt passord </label>
                        <input type="password" name="pass2" class="mid2 form-control" id="pass2" value="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <em><span style="color: #F00">*</span> påkrevde felter</em>
                    </div>
                </div>

                    <h3>Kontakt info</h3>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label>Facebook URL</label>
                            <input type="text" name="facebook" class=" form-control" id="facebook" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'facebook', $userdata->ID ) ); ?>" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label>Twitter</label>
                            <input type="text" name="twitter" class=" form-control" id="twitter" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'twitter', $userdata->ID ) ); ?>" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label>City</label>
                            <input type="text" name="city" class=" form-control" id="city" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'city', $userdata->ID ) ); ?>" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <label>Fylke</label>
                            <select class="form-control" name="province" id="province">
                            <option value="Sør-Trøndelag" <?php selected( 'Sør-Trøndelag', get_the_author_meta( 'province', $user->ID ) ); ?>>Sør-Trøndelag</option>
                            <option value="Nord-Trøndelag" <?php selected( 'Nord-Trøndelag', get_the_author_meta( 'province', $user->ID ) ); ?>>Nord-Trøndelag</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-info" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update" />
                    </div>
                </div>
        </form>
    </div><!-- #content -->

    <div class="col-md-3">
        <?php get_sidebar('right') ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer() ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access the meta data of the user with ID stored in `$user->ID` but the object `$user` is not defined in your code. You are also using an undefined variable `$user_ID`.

The quickest fix in your code would be to change this:

```
get_the_author_meta( 'province', $user->ID ) )
```

With:

```
get_the_author_meta( 'province', $userdata->ID ) )
```

Tip: turn `WP_DEBUG` on to get notice about those kind of errrors.